# Windows cannot format the Drive

Tags: windows, windows-vista, formatting

I had Windows Vista installed in my laptop about 4 years ago. I had no problems, until last month when the Video driver failed to initialize. I tried a **repair**, trying to load the driver from the drivers loaded on the system, copying files on the USB to load the driver from there, repair from Windows Vista installation CD. Nothing worked.

So the only option was to Re-Install Vista, which I could not do on the original "SYSTEM" Drive (C:), as it did not have enough space and I could not Format it previously for a clean install, because I got a BSOD screen every time I tried to boot the system.

I had another logical drive (D:) which had enough space to get my installation on. All good, it started booting from the new install, so what was `D:` drive has now become the `C:`. I now am trying to recover the old `C:` (which is now the D:), most of the files get deleted, however some of them are system files so I could not delete it.

So I thought I would Format the Drive, to get the disk space. But it could not Format it through `Right Click -> Format`. So I went on to **Disk Management**, to do a clean Format, but I got the error `Windows Cannot Format the Drive`.

I understand why, because this (now D:) was the original System Drive and the other one (now C:) still remains as an Active Logical Drive.

How on earth can I get around deleting/formatting the old System drive and set the current Logical drive as the System Drive?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Um, so I’m not exactly sure what you actually did or did not do, but you do know you can format drives in Setup, right? Right now, the boot manager still resides on your old C: partition, that’s why you can’t format it.

Comment: Yes, I know that I could Format my drive on set up. The reason I chose not to do it, is because of the fact I did not want to loose some of my data. So I installed in the Logical drive. Everything is back to normal now. Once my system was up and running, I made a back up of all my data. then reinstalled windows from the scratch with a clean slate of all drives. Things are working as normal.